# How do I add Mono Application to Ubuntu Start Up?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mono

I am very new to Ubuntu & Linux. I have deployed an C# Console Application to an EC2 Instance running Ubuntu 12.10. Currently I am using `mono foldername/appname.exe` to start the app. How do I add this to the start up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you write a bash script for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by creating a script file `/etc/init/app.exe.conf` which contains the below code

```
description "APP Description"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

setuid ubuntu
setgid nogroup
respawn
console log

script
exec mono /opt/folder/app.exe
end script`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the /etc/init/ solution is that you need root privileges to do it.

If you are in the situation of needing the same and not having these privileges, you could use crontab. Do `man crontab` to find out more.